# Git log graph lines crossing each other in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

In IntelliJ based IDE, we often see the two branch lines crossing each other, while if you view the same in Git Graph for VSCode, the two remains non intersecting.

Here in picture attached, the two branches cross each other in mid way seemingly with no visible reason.

Can anyone explain why IntelliJ shows the graph like this?

[image]

Comment: It's just some graph-drawing algorithm they chose. There are a lot of ways to draw graphs. See [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452). Note that GitHub is not relevant here. (Git is barely relevant, in that it provides the underlying graph.) There may be some particular logic behind IntelliJ's graph-drawing algorithm choice, so this is not a bad *question*, but unless they outlined why in some document, or you get hold of one of the IntelliJ authors, there's no clear answer.